# Apollo 11 Moon orbital elements

Tags: the-moon, apollo-program, lunar-landing, apollo-11

I'm simulating several pieces of the Apollo 11 mission.

I'm now at the point of performing lunar landing sequence, and I'm looking for data. I found [this report](https://www.hq.nasa.gov/alsj/nasa58040.pdf), but it only has partial data, while I'm looking for more precise definitions, like orbital elements at PDI (the aforementioned report simply says singular parameters like "48814 ft as altitude", "at 260 nautic miles" of distance, with inertial velocity of 5560 ft/s).

Any suggestion for more systematic data?

thanks in advance!